# Why is Freemasonry considered by many evangelicals to be incompatible with Christianity?

Tags: biblical-basis, comparative-christianity, freemasonry

Many Protestant and Evangelical churches and Christians view Freemasonry as incompatible with Christianity and teach that a Christian should not be a member of the group. What is the basis, biblical or otherwise, for this position?

Comment: Possibly relevant: "[The Freemasonry Threat](http://www.christianitytoday.com/ct/2007/august/7.18.html)" and "[Going where angels fear to tread](http://www.patheos.com/blogs/rogereolson/2011/09/going-where-angels-fear-to-tread-christianity-and-freemasonry/)"

Comment: There's a pretty comprehensive explanation here:
http://fallingmasonry.info/heresy.html

Comment: Related: [How does the Catholic church view Freemasons?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/16621)

Answer (score 14):

<sup>I want to preface this by saying that I have never been a Freemason, and this answer, necessarily will include items that are likely to be disputed by those within Freemasonry.  This can't be avoided if I'm to answer the actual question.  The question is "Why do Evangelicals consider it to be incompatible".  It's not asking if it really is, just why they think it is.</sup>

<sup>In order to answer that, I need to post the things that those who oppose Freemasonry believe.  I have absolutely no idea if those things are true or not, and I'm not here to claim they are or aren't.  I'm just repeating what's in the literature and what's believed of Freemasonry by Christians.</sup>

---

I'm going to use, as my primary resource, a site that's been put up by someone claiming to be an ex-Mason.  It contains much of the same in formation that can be found in other literature.  I've read several books on "cults" and Freemasonry is listed in several of them.  For example, while it's not listed as a cult in this book, the book *[What's the Difference](http://www.abebooks.com/Difference-Ridenour-Fritz-Regal-Books-Ventura/1077328905/bd)* lists Freemasonry in a section called "Nothing New Under the Sun...  Eleven more viewpoints that undermine, challenge, or attack Biblical Christianity".  At any rate, the claims on this site are compatible with most of what I've said.

With all of that out of the way, here are several points about Freemasonry that are incompatible with Christianity:

- [Freemasonry requires each Mason to believe that there is only one God and teaches that all men worship that one God, simply using a variety of different names.](http://www.emfj.org/godbible.htm)  In the case of the Wiccan, he satisfies the requirement for belief in A Supreme Being by believing in the Horned god of Witchcraft.  The Hindu may satisfy the requirement with faith in Vishnu.

  - From a Christian perspective, this is utter nonsense.  **This is also, just about the only point you'd need to show that Freemasonry is incompatible with Christianity.**  Any attempt to say that the God of the Bible is the same as (or even functionally equivalent to for some people) the pagan gods, Allah, or any other is blasphemy, pure and simple, from a Christian perspective.
- [Freemasonry has a plan of salvation](http://www.emfj.org/salvat.htm), which is not based on Christ at all.
- [There is some concern about the oaths made in Freemasonry](http://www.emfj.org/oaths.htm).

  - Follow this link and you'll find an extensive treatment on several issues that show Freemasonry to be incompatible with Christianity

Another site lists other reasons, again, which I've heard before, but can't personally verify.  Again, I'm just answering why some Christians are opposed to Freemasonry.

> - In Freemasonry the god of the secret societies is covertly substituted
>     for the One True God. This false god is identified in the Masonic
>     lodges as "the Great Architect."
> - Masons think that through masonry one can chisel away layers of oneself, similar to how one creates a beautiful statue out of rough
>     stone.  And they think the end result will be no need for God; because
>     they think the perfect Mason is like God. Pages 50-51 of the Mason
>     handbook makes this quite clear - but not to the initiate. Masons are
>     lied to about everything in the 1st three degrees.
> - Masons repeatedly are directed to the "Mystery Religion" and the time man found God in nature.  Almost none of Masonry's teachings come
>     from Christianity.  This 'mystery religion' Masons have joined
>     originated from pagans in ancient Egypt, Chaldea, and in China. The
>     Mystery Religion, Freemasonry and all 'ancient' secret societies have
>     one thing in common. They string you along, just to finally tell you
>     that there is no God; and you are a god, because you follow their
>     teachings, which are:

And finally...

> In the Masonic Lodge everything is symbolic of something else. The
>   name "Lucifer" means "Light Bearer" or "Light Bringer".  Masons point
>   out that the MORNING STAR is Lucifer.  When Masons speak of the "light
>   of Masonry", they actually refer to Lucifer bringing forth the light. 
>   During the lecture for the 32nd degree, Masons are told that the
>   triliteral name for god is composed of three Hindu gods: Brahma,
>   Vishnu and Siva. Siva is a synonym for Satan! Lucifer is honored and
>   revered by Masons as the TRUE GOD!

Comment: I can honestly tell you that those things mentioned are not true and especially in your "finally". Lucifer does mean "Light Bearer" and to the Romans, it is the Morning Star. Please do me a favor and find Lucifer in the Bible. Anywhere in the Bible excluding the King James Version where it's mentioned once.  This answer includes some of the misinformation that has been spread about Freemasonry which has circulated.  The attitude of Freemasonry has been, "say what you want, we know that's not true and we don't care if you join or not."  However, I feel that the truth should be exposed.

Comment: I gave this a +1 because these are indeed the reasons given by Evangelicals for their opposition to Freemasonry. I do question the validity of the information given by former members; generally ex-members of any group are the most biased and least rational source of information about that group. I realize this is probably not the place for that discussion, but I wanted to make a distinction between the validity of the answer and that of the information it contains.

Comment: @DanAndrews: Then ask/answer some appropriate questions. But this answer seems to do exactly what it claims to do: state some of the standard Evangelical objections to Freemasonry. Incidentally, this is what this question requires.

Comment: This is all why I was very careful to include my preface. I think @DanAndrews got that, and I don't blame him for his comments. They weren't argumentative, or even defensive. He didn't vote it down, either. I think he was just making sure nobody took the objection as Truth. I thought his comments were appropriate.

Comment: @Bruce the obvious problem being: if the information is restricted to members, and active members are silent: ex members is the best we have. That doesn't make it automatically false either. I've heard compelling and **correlated** accounts from multiple ex-scientologists, for example. And ex-members of mainstream religions who've seen "behind the curtain" at higher levels and didn't like what they saw.

Comment: While a great answer, I would like to point out an issue: "Any attempt to say that the God of the Bible is the same as [...] Allah, is blasphemy" is not really true. "Allah" is just the Arabic word for God, just as "Gott" is the German word for God. Arabic-speaking Christians also use this same word to refer to God.

Comment: @vsz: The God of the Bible has a Son, and the Muslims claim that their god has no son. They are not the same God, no matter what the Muslims may call their god.

Comment: @Steve Those are very dangerous waters that you're treading on, the Jewish God has no son either.

Comment: @TheFreemason Jesus Christ disagrees with you: Matthew 22:41-46.

Comment: @Steve and the Jewish faith would disagree with Matthew.

Comment: @TheFreemason Agreed! That's why God turned to the Gentiles -- Matthew 21:33-41.

Comment: Lucifer is, in a way, the light bringer. It is a huge jump to go from Light Bringer to God though. Lucifer exists for a reason, just like every other aspect of God's plan. Lucifer's purpose was to bring light to mankind by tempting Adam and Eve in Eden. Without the fall of Adam at Lucifer's hands mankind would still be in darkness. He truly is a necessary evil in the purest sense.

Answer (score 2):

Freemasonry is a fraternity that does not refuse people due to their specific religious preferences.  But there are some exceptions.  For an example, an atheist is strictly and universally (under the grand lodge of England) not permitted to join.  Because we allow multiple faiths, some people take issue with the fraternity.  Such as Christians are taught to not to yoke with unbelievers

**2 Corinthians 6:14 NIV**

> Do not be yoked together with unbelievers. For what do righteousness
>   and wickedness have in common? Or what fellowship can light have with
>   darkness?

Because Freemasonry does not support a single specific religion but requests that it members subscribe to a religion and as mentioned "yoking", some people such as the [Sovereign Pontiff. Maximillian Kolbe](http://www.angelusonline.org/index.php?section=articles&subsection=show_article&article_id=2956) believe that implies that they are against Christianity.

> This mortal hatred of the Church, of Christ, and of His Vicar on earth
>   is not just an outburst of misguided individuals, but rather a
>   systematic action that proceeds from the principle of Freemasonry: the
>   destruction of all religion, but especially the Catholic religion.
>   [Pisma Ojca Maksymiliana Marii Kolbego franciszkanina, Niepokalanow,
>   maszynopsis, 1970; English tr. from The Immaculata Our Ideal, by Fr.
>   Karl Stehlin (Warsaw, 2005), p.39]….

Christians who do not believe you should be friends with non-Christians would have a problem with the fraternity.

Freemason takes obligations or makes promises which some Christians dislike.  So for example, I promise to not allow an atheist to join.  Some Christians feel that you should not make promises like that to yourself or in front of God.

Comment: While interesting to hear one persons' defense of Freemasonry, most of this is off topic for this question. The question is why so many evangelicals consider it incompattable with their beliefs. The note about unequal yoking is only a very small piece of that and not even specific to the beliefs of either group. Most Evangelicals DO believe in being friends with non-Christian's, don't put much stock in the bit about unequal yoking in settings other than marriage and sometimes business, yet there are still fundamental belief conflicts between them. Those are what would answer this question.

Comment: I answered the question as noted from the viewpoint of a Freemason.  The way that Freemasons understand the concern of Evangelicals.  I understand that you may not like the answer for some reason.  However I strongly feel that it's an important answer to this question for education and should not be deleted even if it's down voted many times.

Comment: @Caleb "Many Protestant and Evangelical churches and Christians..."  Sounds like it's more than just Evangelicals - just FYI

Comment: Excuse me? That line of reasoning is exactly what will NOT work as a reason to keep this. Change up the players to see my point. If a question comes along asking about why X group considers Y theology to be wrong, only answers from X perspective are permitted. If Y comes along and fills up the space with a defense of their views without answering the question about X's beliefs, their answer is OFF TOPIC. If you want to post this on a question about why Freemason Christians don't see their views in conflict, that's fine. But this is _not that question_.

Comment: So let me get this straight, and answer that is full of non-truths and rumors is correct.  But one that's focused on truths and references is considered off topic.  I see how that makes sense!

Comment: The truthiness of X's beliefs are not up for debate in this forum. All this forum ideally concerns itself with is clarifying the contents, meaning, and implications of X's beliefs *to X assuming they are true*.

Comment: Rather than deleting this answer (since most of it was inappropriate content for this question) I have removed most of the content. I do not believe what is left is actually the right answer to this question, but the community can judge whether that is actually the evangelical issue or not.